# Android studio blank screen on Create project

Tags: android

I am getting a blank screen on android studio when trying to create a new project.
When I hover the mouse over the location of the project name it actually changes the pointer to the "enter text" pointer and if I do and press enter it creates the project. But I can't see any text or boxes in the "Create new project" window.
Any ideas on what is causing the problem?[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3uVO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think the probably problems are as follows:
1. The installation of Android Studio. There are 2 ways to install AS, one is download the zip and open the /bin/studio.exe directly, such as the previews version. one is to download the install file to install on the computer
2. Check you sdk is installed and configured correctly.